# check if runSequence fail

Tags: gulp

I have the following task on my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('build', function (cb) {
  return runSequence(
    'clean',
    'tsd',
    'ts-lint',
    ['sass', 'copy-assets', 'ts-compile', 'templates', 'copy-vendor'],
    'karma-once',
    'index',
    cb
  );
});
```

How can I check if any of the tasks in a `runSequence` fail in gulp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The callback function that `runSequence` accepts as last argument, gives you an `err` object if some task failed.

```
runSequence('mytask', ['othertask'], function(err) {
    if (err) {
        // you can check for err.message or err.task for the name of the task
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks. error handling in gulp is much more difficult than with grunt